# declaring object using variable

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to use a variable when declaring an object:

```
var name1 = "object1";
var data1 = 3;
create_object(name1, data1);

function create_object(name, data) {
  var x = {
    name: data
  }
  return x
}
```

I want x to be stored as

```
var x = {
  object1: 3
}
```

But my function will make

```
var x = {
  name: 3
}
```

Is there a way to pass a variable when declaring the name of a child inside an object?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

To specify a name of a property from a variable you need to use the square brackets notation like this:

```
function create_object(name, data) {
  var x = {};
  x[name] = data;
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Or `{[name]: data}`.

Comment: Obvious duplicate questions should be closed in favor of the canonical, not answered over and over